# How to tranpose snowflake table with arrays

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a result of a query that looks like this:

```
|KEY |VALUE                 |
----------------------------
|C1| |{1,2,3,4,5}           |
|C2| |{ 'a','b','c','d','e'}|
|C3| |{1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0} |
```

How to convert it into:

```
|C1|C2 |C3 |
-----------
|1 |'a'|1.0|
|2 |'b'|2.0|
|3 |'c'|3.0|
|4 |'d'|4.0|
|5 |'d'|5.0|
```

Comment: Can you share the query that gives those results too?

Comment: Something like this: SELECT
  Record.Key, Record.Value
    
FROM (select * from SRC limit 1)  
    ,   LATERAL FLATTEN (input=> OBJ, MODE=>'OBJECT' ) as Record
; whre src is a json object with properties as arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Record.Key, Record.Value 
FROM (
    SELECT parse_json('{"C1":[1,2,3,4,5],"C2":[ \'a\',\'b\',\'c\',\'d\',\'e\'],"C3":[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]}') as json
) , LATERAL FLATTEN (input=> json, MODE=>'OBJECT' ) as Record ;
```

gives:

```
KEY VALUE
C1  [    1,    2,    3,    4,    5  ]
C2  [    "a",    "b",    "c",    "d",    "e"  ]
C3  [    1,    2,    3,    4,    5  ]
```

so if you have a single object of JSON that you want the equal sized arrays of values:

```
SELECT 
     json:C1[r.index] as C1 
    ,json:C2[r.index] as C2 
    ,json:C3[r.index] as C3 
FROM (
    SELECT parse_json('{"C1":[1,2,3,4,5],"C2":[ \'a\',\'b\',\'c\',\'d\',\'e\'],"C3":[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]}') as json
) , LATERAL FLATTEN (input=> json:C1, MODE=>'ARRAY' ) as r ;
```

gives

```
C1  C2    C3
1   "a"   1
2   "b"   2
3   "c"   3
4   "d"   4
5   "e"   5
```

where-as if you have many batches of the above object types in an array:

```
SELECT 
    r.index as batch
    ,r.value:C1[q.index] as C1 
    ,r.value:C2[q.index] as C2 
    ,r.value:C3[q.index] as C3 
FROM (
    SELECT parse_json('[{"C1":[1,2,3,4,5],"C2":[ \'a\',\'b\',\'c\',\'d\',\'e\'],"C3":[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]},{"C1":[6,7,8,9,10],"C2":[ \'a\',\'b\',\'c\',\'d\',\'e\'],"C3":[11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0]}]') as json
) , LATERAL FLATTEN (input=> json, MODE=>'ARRAY' ) as r
  , LATERAL FLATTEN (input=> r.value:C1, MODE=>'ARRAY' ) as q;
```

gives:

```
BATCH   C1  C2  C3
0       1   "a" 1
0       2   "b" 2
0       3   "c" 3
0       4   "d" 4
0       5   "e" 5
1       6   "a" 11
1       7   "b" 12
1       8   "c" 13
1       9   "d" 14
1       10  "e" 15
```

Comment: Thansks Simeon, the second query with multiple rows does not work though.

Comment: @user2555515 it works for the data I provided, given I had to guess what your data looked like, it not working for your data is not a surprise at all. But the hope is you can see how I made it work for the data I have, and can see how you use the tools to work with your data. Or failing that you could alter the question to include the data you have and then you might be an exact answer.

Comment: But you provided your own data. Just copying your answer and pasting into Snowflake worksheet does not produce any result. ( your first example works great though, thanks for that one !) Sorry my knowledge of Snowflake does not let me find an easy way of fixing your second example.

Comment: @user2555515 omg, a complete cut'n'paste error on my behalf. put the correct second lot of SQL